# Display shapefile data - Leaflet 1.4.0

Tags: shapefile, leaflet, overlay

I am using Leaflet 1.4.0  and a beginner with Leaflet and JavaScript.

I try to display shapefile data on my webmap with Leaflet. But it doesn't work.
All the data (.shp, index.html... ) in WGS84 are on my computer, in the same directory.

My JavaScript code is:

```
var shapeLayer = new L.Shapefile("data/QualiAgro.zip");
```

I get the following Console message:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at https://some-url-here. (Reason: additional
> information here).

If I understood this is a CORS problem (url). But I don't know how to do?
Does any one have any idea?

I also try the shapefile data with: http://leaflet.calvinmetcalf.com/#3/32.69/10.55
There's no display.

I have installed "Wampserver2" on my computer to run my html from a local server.
I changed the JavaScript code :

```
    var shapeLayer = new L.Shapefile("http//localhost:80/data/QualiAgro.zip");
```

But I still have the same problem with no message Console for the mistake.

Comment: I recommend abandoning the shp altogether. Put the shp in postgres and use one of the many middleware options and pull it in through leaflet

Comment: you can also convert the shp to geojson and there are a few ways to avoid the CORs problem

Answer (score 0):

Open command line and navigate to the folder in where your project is, and then run this command: `python3 -m http.server`

This may solve your problem as mentioned in the comments.